# Set default value in QuerySelectField (Form initialized by object)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to set the default value in a QuerySelectField. If the Form is empty (add an object) - setting the default value works fine. But if the Form is initialized before (edit an object) i have no idea how to set the default value.
Ive already tried the formfactory suggested here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046808/wtforms-i-cant-seem-to-dynamically-give-a-queryselectfield-a-default-value)

... does not work...

We have companies, branches(of the companies) and Bankaccounts.
Each branch belongs to a company and has his bankaccount.
If I edit a branch the appropiate company and bankaccount has to be set as default in the dropdwon.
So im trying to handle this for two days now... - where is my mistake? Please help!

C.

Here are the snippets:

the models:

```
class TBranch(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 't_branch'

idt_branch = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, info='ID of the branch')
t_company_idt_company = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('t_company.idt_company'), nullable=False, index=True,
                                  info='id of the company')
shortname = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, unique=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, info='Bankverbindung - taken from t_kto')
mail = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, info='mailadress of the branch')
idt_bankaccount = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('t_bankaccount.idt_bankaccount'), nullable=False, index=True)

t_bankaccount = db.relationship('TBankaccount',
                                primaryjoin='TBranch.idt_bankaccount == TBankaccount.idt_bankaccount',
                                backref='t_branches')
t_company = db.relationship('TCompany', primaryjoin='TBranch.t_company_idt_company == TCompany.idt_company',
                            backref='t_branches')


class TCompany(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 't_company'

idt_company = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, info='ID of the company')
company = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, info='company - xxxxx')
longname = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False,
                     info='Name of the company (xxxx)')
street = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, info='Strasse')
plz = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False, info='plz of the company')
city = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, info='City of the company')
phone = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, info='Telephone number of the Company')
fax = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, info='Fax number of the company')
web = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, info='Webadress of the company')
taxid = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, info='Steuernmmer')
firmenbuch = db.Column(db.String(45), info='Firmenbuchnummer')
gericht = db.Column(db.String(45), info='Gerichtsstand')


class TBankaccount(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 't_bankaccount'

idt_bankaccount = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, info='ID of the bankaccount dataset')
name = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, info='Name of the bankaccount')
iban = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, info='iban of the bankaccount')
bic = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, info='bic of the bankaccount')
```

The form - setting default works if no object is passed

```
class BranchForm(FlaskForm):
"""
Form for admin to add or edit the branches (Schulzweig)
"""
company = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: TCompany.query.all(),
                           get_pk=lambda a: a.idt_company,
                           # default=lambda: TCompany.query.filter(TCompany.idt_company == 2).one_or_none(),
                           get_label=lambda a: a.longname)
shortname = StringField('Shortname', validators=[DataRequired()])
name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
mail = StringField('Mail', validators=[DataRequired()])
bankaccount = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: TBankaccount.query.all(),
                               # default=lambda: TBankaccount.query.filter(TBankaccount.name == "xxx").one_or_none(),
                               get_label="name")
submit = SubmitField('Speichern')
```

The formfactory (setting default does not work...)

```
def add_branch_form_factory(default_company, default_bankaccount):
print("addbranch, company: " + str(default_company))
print("addbranch, bankaccount: " + str(default_bankaccount))

class AddBranchForm(FlaskForm):
    """
    Form for admin to add or edit the branches (Schulzweig)
    """
    company = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: TCompany.query.all(),
                               #get_pk=lambda c: c.idt_company,
                               default=TCompany.query.filter_by(idt_company=default_company).one_or_none(),
                               get_label="longname")
    shortname = StringField('Shortname', validators=[DataRequired()])
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    mail = StringField('Mail', validators=[DataRequired()])
    bankaccount = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: TBankaccount.query.all(),
                                   # get_pk=lambda b: b.idt_bankaccount,
                                   default=TBankaccount.query.filter(
                                       TBankaccount.idt_bankaccount == default_bankaccount).one_or_none(),
                                   get_label=lambda b: b.name)
    submit = SubmitField('Speichern')
```

The view

```
@admin.route('/branches/edit/<int:idt_branch>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_branch(idt_branch):
"""
Edit a branch
:param idt_branch: the id of the branch to edit
:return: redirection url
"""
check_admin()
add_branch = False

branch = TBranch.query.get_or_404(idt_branch)
print(branch)
# form = BranchForm(obj=branch)
AddBranchForm = add_branch_form_factory(default_company=branch.t_company_idt_company, default_bankaccount=branch.idt_bankaccount)
form = AddBranchForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    branch.t_company_idt_company = form.company.data.idt_company
    branch.shortname = form.shortname.data
    branch.name = form.name.data
    branch.mail = form.mail.data
    branch.idt_bankaccount = form.bankaccount.data.idt_bankaccount
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Schulzweig erfolgreich geändert!')
    # redirect to the departments page
    return redirect(url_for('admin.list_branches'))
form.company.data = branch.t_company.longname
form.shortname.data = branch.shortname
form.name.data = branch.name
form.mail.data = branch.mail
form.bankaccount.data = branch.idt_bankaccount
return render_template('admin/branches/branch.html', action="Edit",add_branch=add_branch,
                       branch=branch,
                       form=form, title="Schulzweig bearbeiten")
```

and finally the html

```
<td>
     <a href="{{ url_for('admin.edit_branch', idt_branch=branch.idt_branch) }}">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Bearbeiten
     </a>
</td>
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be the problem? Do you have any errors running this code or default value just doesn't show up? Also, have you checked this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579373/sqlalchemy-wtforms-set-default-selected-value-for-queryselectfield ? seems to be quite similar to your question

Comment: @AntonioMargaretti Thanx for response! There are no errors running this code. But the default value is not shown in Dropdown. Dropdwons are populated with companys/bankaccounts but the active entries in the dropdowns are the first entries from the companies/bankaccounts list - not the values assigned to the branch that ist edited. I m trying the slutions of ur link - without success so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing bankaccount and company objects to the form solved the problem. Thanx to Antonio for the link with the hint!

Heres the code (for edit_branch):

```
branch = TBranch.query.get_or_404(idt_branch)
bankaccount = TBankaccount.query.filter(TBankaccount.idt_bankaccount == branch.idt_bankaccount).one_or_none()
company = TCompany.query.filter(TCompany.idt_company == branch.t_company_idt_company).one_or_none()
form = BranchForm(obj=branch, company=company, bankaccount=bankaccount)
```